# Replace multiple line breaks by a single one in Google Docs

Tags: regex, google-docs

Only [Google Sheets supports captures](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/62754#regular_expressions) in "Find and replace" based on Regex ; I am struggling to do something like this that could work on Google Docs.

[image: Find and replace, double line breaks on Google Docs]

Is there a simple way that I missed to do so with Docs?

Comment: Maybe the line endings are CRLF? If `(\r?\n)\r?\n` => `$1` does not work, then there is another issue.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew lines are matching properly, but the syntax "replace with the first capture – $1" is not available on Google Docs. I am looking at an alternate solution.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

According to Google Docs [documentation](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/62754#regular_expressions), you can only use capturing groups in Google Sheets.
However you can replace multiple newlines without using a capturing group, for example with a positive lookahead:

```
\n(?=\n)
```

And replace that with empty string.

[image]

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Nope. I just tried it and it worked.

Comment: Thanks, you're a savior.